# sequelize-cli returning 'Unknown arguments' error

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In my SailsJS app, when I enter the command into the terminal:

```
sequelize db:seed:all
```

I get the response:

```
Unknown arguments: models, username, password, database, host, dialect
```

Also when I run:

```
sequelize -v
```

I get back:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 6.2.1, CLI: 3.2.0, ORM: 4.28.6]

WARNING: This version of Sequelize CLI is not fully compatible with 
Sequelize v4. https://github.com/sequelize/cli#sequelize-support
```

I am connected to the db and I am able to run my app as well as update the db from the client.  The problems seems to be totally restricted to Sequelize/Sequelize-CLI.

Comment: Try to upgrade cli to `4.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

This is because sequelize did not get a configuration file. You need to create a separate configuration file for this.
Example file:

```
module.exports = {
    database: 'dbname',
    host: 'hostenv',
    password: 'password',
    port: '5432',
    username: 'dbuser',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    pool: {
            max:5,
            min:0,
            idle:10000
         }
}
```

Now you can run:
`sequelize --config=sequelize-config.js db:seed:all`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see your seed file, You can use sequelize-cli@3 (There is no sequelize-cli@4.x or pre production version yet), it will work with sequelize@4. Only incompatibility will be this [sequelize/cli#470](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/pull/470).

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your sequelize library can not find the config file. so to solve the problem you can point your sequelize to the config file in the project the connect to your local database by using this commad and parameters

```
sequelize --config=directory-for-/config.js db:seed:all
```

then wala you can run the successfully